# Turltebot laser striking frame in gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently experimenting with navigation for a simulated turtlebot using the turtlebot_navigation package.  I was having trouble getting a stable position estimate when I noticed that the simulated LIDAR appears to be striking the frame of the robot which appears to be interefering with the pose estimate generated by the amcl package.  I have modified the minimum range of the laser to 0.3m, but this does seem to be a temporary solution.

Should the simulated sensor be moved so that is does not strike the frame, or is there a method for directing the navigation system to ignore LIDAR returns that do not meet specific criteria?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48611/turltebot-laser-striking-frame-in-gazebo-simulation/) by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 586 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simulated sensor is designed to work the same as the real sensor, which also can hit the poles.

Typically obstacle avoidance algorithms have methods for eliminating self observations. Commonly you ignore anything inside the footprint or known to be near parts of the robot model.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0